# lazy load public class data member in PHP

Tags: php, lazy-loading, public-members

I want to lazy load the public data members of a class in PHP. Assume we have the following class:

```
<?php
class Dummy
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $status_indicator;
}
?>
```

If `$name`, `$age` and `$status_indicator` were private data members I would lazy load them via their getter methods, but since they are public - I am unclear as to how to lazy load them. Is this possible?

**EDIT**:
Someone commented that there is a method called `__get` which might help to solve this issue, but I didn't understand it.

Comment: I think it can be by lazy load of that class.

Comment: ..or via the `__get` magic method

Comment: You can hide the data (e.g. in an array) and provide access to them using the magic __get() and __set() methods.

Comment: You can lazy load object, meaning to create instance in the time of the first call. When you create instance, memory for non-static members is allocated. I am not sure what do you mean by "lazy load the member"

Comment: @JanTuroň yeah create the instance when you need them ,

Comment: __get() is method "magically" called when you try to read inaccessible attribute (private or non-existent) - it doesn't work with public members. Did I get you right? (See my answer)

Comment: It's not a good idea, there should be almost no cases where such an approach is warranted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) to simulate public members which are really dynamically loaded on first access. When you attempt to access an undefined member of an object, PHP will invoke `__get` and pass it the name of the member you attempted to access. For example, accessing `$x->my_variable` would invoke `__get("my_variable")` if the class had defined an `__get_` method.

In this example, `$dummy->name` indirectly invokes the getter method `getName`, which initializes a private member named `$_name` on first access:

```
<?php
class Dummy
{
  private $_name;

  public function __get($var) {
    if ($var == 'name') {
      return $this->getName();
    } else if ($var == 'age') {
      // ...
    } else {
      throw "Undefined variable $var";
    }
  }

  public function getName() {
    if (is_null($this->_name)) {
      // Initialize and cache the value for $name
      $this->_name = expensive_function();
    }
    return $this->_name;
  }
}

$dummy = new Dummy();
echo $dummy->name;
```

You could similarly define and invoke other accessors like `getAge`.

Comment: fine and for the other members how to make the getter for the other members , i am new to php

Comment: is it $var =='_name' or without the underscore ?

Comment: Yes. The `$var` parameter will contain the name of the variable that was accessed.

Comment: fine you declare the variable as $_name and in the if statement you check the name without the underscore '_'

Comment: @user4o01 Because in the first case, I'm checking against a **string**, which contains `"name"`. In the second case, I'm accessing a private variable named `$_name`. They're different. If you don't get this, you should stop what you're doing and read a PHP tutorial. This is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I used in a recent project:

```php
class EnhancedObject {
    #Store cached properties here
    private $lazyProperties = array();

    #Allow $object->prop to alias to $object->getProperty().
    #Also, allow caching of $object->loadProp() to $object->prop
    public function __get($property) {
        $getter = "get".ucfirst($property);
        $loader = "load".ucfirst($property);

        if(method_exists($this, $getter)) {
            return $this->$getter();
        }
        elseif(method_exists($this, $loader)) {
            if(!isset($this->lazyProperties[$property])) {
                $this->lazyProperties[$property] = $this->$loader();
            }
            return $this->lazyProperties[$property];
        }
    }

    #Allow $object->prop = $value to alias to $object->setProperty($value).
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $setter = "set".ucfirst($property);
        $loader = "load".ucfirst($property);

        if (method_exists($this, $setter)) {
            return $this->$setter($value);
        }
        elseif(method_exists($this, $loader)) {
            $this->lazyProperties[$property] = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This means you only have to mess with the magic `__get` and `set` once, and then simply naming your methods the right things will make the behave as getters, setters, and lazy initializers.

### Usage

```php
class Dummy extends EnhancedObject {
    public $name;
    public $age;

    #Complex getters
    public function getSummary() {
        return "{$this->name}, aged {$this->age}";
    }

    #Cached getters for expensive operations
    public function loadStatusCount($id) {
        doExpensiveStuff();
        return 42;
    }
}

$d = new Dummy();
$d->name = "John Doe"
$d->age = 35

#getters
echo $d->summary; # echos "John Doe, aged 35"

#Lazy-initialized properties
echo $d->statusCount; # runs `doExpensiveStuff()`, echoing 42
echo $d->statusCount; # echos 42
echo $d->statusCount; # echos 42
```

Comment: If you use the code in the top half of this post, you can then extend your class from `EnhancedObject`, and then if you define a method `loadXYZ()`, you can do `myobj->xyz`, and it will run that method to lazy-initialize it.

Comment: @user4o01 I've updated my usage example to fit your situation

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comments, you could use an array of fields and a little magic method magic to handle the loading operation:

```
<?php
class Dummy
{
    protected $fields = array(
        'name' => null, 
        'age' => null,
        'etc' => null
    );

    public function __get ($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->fields)) {
            if ($this->fields[$key] === null) {
                // do some kind of loading operation to set $value
                $this->fields[$key] = $value;
            }
            return $this->fields[$key];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove them and use magic method [__get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

Something like:

```
class Dummy 
{ 
   public function __get($var_name) 
   {
      switch ($var_name) 
      {
        case 'name':
            // lazy load here
            return $val;
            break;

        case 'age':
            // lazy load here
            return $val;
            break;

        case 'number_of_status':
            // lazy load here
            return $val;
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: look very nice but why the break statement after the return?!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `__get()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if ($name == "age" and $this->age == null)) {
        // lazy load $this->age
        return $this->age;
    }

    return $this->$name;
}
```

Comment: PHP uses "&&" or "and": http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all: This is exactly the reason why you should use getter/setter methods. That way, you can add additional logic to the process of retrieving the data.

Here is an example how to achieve public-member-like access using __get():

```
class Dummy {
    private $lazyMembers = array(
        'name' => 'NameOfTheClass'
    );

    public function __get($key) {
        if (isset($this->lazyMembers[$key])) {
            $obj = new $this->lazyMembers[$key]();
            $this->$key = $obj;
            return $obj;
        }

        // ..throw exception or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same example as OP, you can't lazy load public members as you would protected/private. There are several work arounds which is like OP mentioned, using the getter methods to do the lazy loading logic. `__get()` would not work with public members of the same class because the direct access to the members means `__get()` would never be called. Hiding them in an array would make `__get` or `getter` methods work but thats basically the same as removing them from the public visibility which is obviously what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, you wanted to know if you can overload *public* variables.

You already knew about the __get($name) magic method, right? Or maybe you were talking about *getName()*, *getAge()* and *getStatus_Indicator()*.

In any case as public properties you can't tap into the magic methods.

I'll just list them for proof of concept.

### Example 1

```
<?php

class Dummy {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $status_indicator;

    public function __construct() {
        foreach($this AS $name => $value) {
            $this->$name = new LazyLoader($this, $name);
        }
    }
}



class LazyLoader {
    protected $object;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($object, $name) {
        $this->object = $object;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function load() {
        /* find the necessary $data somehow */
        $name = $this->name;
        $this->object->$name = $data;
        /*
           after the first call to LazyLoader::load
           the property no longer points to a LazyLoad
           object, but to the intended value
        */
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return($this->load());
    }
}

?>
```

### Example 2

```
<?php

class LazyCollectionWrapper extends ArrayObject {
    public function __construct($objects = array()) {
        parent::__construct($objects);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        $this->collection[$offset]->lazyLoad();
        return($this->collection[$offset]);
    }
}

class Dummy {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $status_indicator;

    public function lazyLoad() {
        /* load stuff here */
    }
}

?>
```

### Example 3

```
<?php

class Dummy {
    public function __get() {
        /*
          load stuff here because undefined
          properties are caught by __get too
        */
    }
}

?>
```

Example 3 is least informative about the structure but as far as memory is concerned it's the best way to do it. We were talking about lazy loading stuf... i.e. not loading useless stuff into memory right?

I say this because:

```
class x { protected $var1 = array(); protected $var2 = 0.0; }
```

Eats up more memory than

```
class x { protected $var1; protected $var2; }
```

And even more than

```
class x { }
```

I've tested it by building millions of objects and comparing peak memory usages.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good coding style to have such "lazy-loading-properties". If you need some lazy loading values, simply use a get-method without any public property.

However I like this problem :) and I also like the most solutions, but I'd also like to add my generic solution here:

```php
class Dummy
{
    private $_name;
    private $_age;
    private $_number_of_status;

    public function __get($name) {
        $var = "_".$name;
        $lazyLoadingMethod = "_load_".$name;
        if (!method_exists($this, $lazyLoadingMethod )) {
            trigger_error("Cannot access private property Dummy::$$name", E_USER_ERROR);
            return;
        }
        if (!isset($this->$var)) {
            $this->$var = $this->$lazyLoadingMethod();
        }
        return $this->$var;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $var = "_".$name;
        $settingMethod = "_set_".$name;
        if (!method_exists($this, $settingMethod )) {
            trigger_error("Cannot access private property Dummy::$$name", E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            $this->$settingMethod($value);
        }
    }

    public function _load_age() {
        // lazy load here
        return 42;
    }

    public function _set_name($name) {
        echo "my new name is $name";
        $this->_name = $name;
    }
}
```

With this class you even have a read/write mechanism for your properties, so "age" can be read but not set, and "name" can be set but not read:

```php
$d = new Dummy();
echo $d->age; //=> 42
$d->name = "Jon"; //my new name is Jon
echo $d->name; //=> Fatal error: Cannot access private property Dummy::$name in ...
$d->age = 100; //=> Fatal error: Cannot access private property Dummy::$age in ...
```